# Run linear regression on the model selected with FWD

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, linear-regression, coefficients

I have found the best subset of coefficients using Forward stepwise selection (FWD) and I now need to run a linear model on these 12 coefficients. I can see which are the coefficients using the function:

```
coef(fwd.fit, 12)
```

Which outputs this:

```
                (Intercept)                StatusDeveloping 
              51.7028848905                   -1.0094947279 
            Adult_Mortality                         Alcohol 
              -0.0177131732                   -0.1749479987 
     percentage_expenditure                     Hepatitis_B 
               0.0003301079                   -0.0138232149 
                        BMI               under_five_deaths 
               0.0567848563                   -0.0011064273 
                      Polio                      Diphtheria 
               0.0183144137                    0.0397637796 
                   HIV_AIDS Income_composition_of_resources 
              -0.4369644695                    9.2369148554 
                  Schooling 
               0.9244156376
```

When I run linear regression I receive this error:

```
lm_sub.life = lm(Life_expectancy ~ coef(fwd.fit, 12), data = train)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Life_expectancy ~ coef(fwd.fit,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'coef(fwd.fit, 12)')
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I run a linear regression on these 12 selected coefficients?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Stepwise lm returns an object of class lm so there is usually no need to create it again.
However, you can extract the formula and coeeficients from it and predict it on new data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
```

create example data

```r
min.model <- lm(displ ~ year, data = mpg)
biggest <- formula(lm(displ~., mpg))
fwd.fit <- step(min.model, direction='forward', scope = biggest)
#> Start:  AIC=117.71
#> displ ~ year
#> 
#>                Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC
#> + cyl           1    328.50  51.92 -346.32
#> + model        37    328.44  51.97 -274.09
#> + cty           1    244.92 135.49 -121.86
#> + manufacturer 14    252.94 127.47 -110.14
#> + hwy           1    228.40 152.01  -94.94
#> + class         6    218.88 161.53  -70.72
#> + drv           2    184.80 195.61  -33.93
#> + trans         9     52.33 328.08  101.08
#> + fl            4     15.96 364.45  115.68
#> <none>                      380.41  117.71
#> 
#> Step:  AIC=-346.32
#> displ ~ year + cyl
#> 
#>                Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC
#> + model        37    33.744 18.175 -517.94
#> + manufacturer 14    21.598 30.320 -444.18
#> + class         6    18.031 33.887 -434.15
#> + drv           2    11.025 40.893 -398.18
#> + hwy           1     3.478 48.440 -360.55
#> + cty           1     2.927 48.991 -357.90
#> <none>                      51.918 -346.32
#> + fl            4     0.802 51.116 -341.97
#> + trans         9     2.170 49.748 -338.31
#> 
#> Step:  AIC=-517.94
#> displ ~ year + cyl + model
#> 
#>         Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC
#> + fl     4   1.86890 16.306 -535.33
#> <none>               18.175 -517.94
#> + cty    1   0.09984 18.075 -517.23
#> + hwy    1   0.00439 18.170 -516.00
#> + class  2   0.00196 18.173 -513.96
#> + trans  9   0.93835 17.236 -512.34
#> 
#> Step:  AIC=-535.33
#> displ ~ year + cyl + model + fl
#> 
#>         Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC
#> + cty    1   0.43757 15.868 -539.70
#> <none>               16.306 -535.33
#> + hwy    1   0.08981 16.216 -534.62
#> + class  2   0.03599 16.270 -531.85
#> + trans  9   0.63534 15.670 -526.63
#> 
#> Step:  AIC=-539.7
#> displ ~ year + cyl + model + fl + cty
#> 
#>         Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC
#> <none>               15.868 -539.70
#> + hwy    1   0.10267 15.765 -539.21
#> + class  2   0.02333 15.845 -536.04
#> + trans  9   0.65107 15.217 -531.50
```

see coefs of selected covariates

```r
coef(fwd.fit)
#>                 (Intercept)                        year 
#>                -30.98134801                  0.01625489 
#>                         cyl                     modela4 
#>                  0.44738593                 -0.87455801 
#>             modela4 quattro             modela6 quattro 
#>                 -0.91773711                 -0.78847214 
#>                 modelaltima     modelc1500 suburban 2wd 
#>                 -0.14655463                  0.93661001 
#>                  modelcamry           modelcamry solara 
#>                 -0.28698855                 -0.31555998 
#>            modelcaravan 2wd                  modelcivic 
#>                 -0.10737368                 -0.74398174 
#>                modelcorolla               modelcorvette 
#>                 -0.55444347                  1.39549893 
#>      modeldakota pickup 4wd            modeldurango 4wd 
#>                  0.21531620                  0.48485472 
#>         modelexpedition 2wd           modelexplorer 4wd 
#>                  0.46170667                  0.27944586 
#>        modelf150 pickup 4wd           modelforester awd 
#>                  0.36805402                 -0.21735478 
#>     modelgrand cherokee 4wd             modelgrand prix 
#>                  0.26929199                  0.12507030 
#>                    modelgti            modelimpreza awd 
#>                 -0.66715476                 -0.22089847 
#>                  modeljetta        modelk1500 tahoe 4wd 
#>                 -0.61694542                  1.11914119 
#> modelland cruiser wagon 4wd                 modelmalibu 
#>                  0.52910280                 -0.17670568 
#>                 modelmaxima        modelmountaineer 4wd 
#>                 -0.40297327                  0.22357335 
#>                modelmustang          modelnavigator 2wd 
#>                  0.21991003                  0.65935846 
#>             modelnew beetle                 modelpassat 
#>                 -0.49458351                 -0.81389164 
#>         modelpathfinder 4wd    modelram 1500 pickup 4wd 
#>                  0.01257785                  0.39850464 
#>            modelrange rover                 modelsonata 
#>                 -0.49325335                 -0.43356086 
#>                modeltiburon      modeltoyota tacoma 4wd 
#>                 -0.75940748                  0.02375394 
#>                         fld                         fle 
#>                  0.17999447                 -0.54779979 
#>                         flp                         flr 
#>                  0.16555105                 -0.04149358 
#>                         cty 
#>                 -0.03766769
```

is already a lm so no need to create a new one

```r
class(fwd.fit)
#> [1] "lm"
```

get selected covariates

```r
as.formula(fwd.model)
#> Error in as.formula(fwd.model): object 'fwd.model' not found
```

make predictions on new data

```r
predict(fwd.fit, newdata = head(mpg))
#>        1        2        3        4        5        6 
#> 1.914687 1.801684 1.985646 1.947978 2.884794 2.809459
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, is there a way to extract the names of those coefficients to use them for another linear regression as I was asking?

Comment: Do `fwd.fit %>% coefficients() %>% names()` or `fwd.fit %>% as.formula() %>% as.character() %>% last() %>% str_split("[ +]+") %>% purrr::simplify()` after loading `tidyverse`